# Django ORM - SQL part of WHERE if parameter is null

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have a problem in django trying to exclude or include part of the filter if the parameter is null.

I have 4 parameters in my model:
StartDate, EndDate, Severity and Source.

The filter can have one or more of these parameters. If I pass 1 of them the others could be `None` unless they are defined.

I was able to solve my problem with query raw by doing

`WHERE (param IS NULL OR param=param)`

and the same in django

```
"""SELECT * FROM mymanagelogs_logs WHERE (%(severity)s IS NULL OR severity=%(severity)s) AND (%(source)s IS NULL OR source=%(source)s) AND (%(start_date)s IS NULL OR timestamp >= %(start_date)s) AND (%(end_date)s IS NULL OR timestamp <= %(end_date)s)""",
params={'severity': severity, 'source': source, 'start_date':start, 'end_date':end}
)
```

but I can't do the same QuerySet:

```
objects.filter(Q(date__range=(start, end)) & (Q(severity=severity) | Q(severity=None))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and build the queryset incrementally. For example:

```py
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

if severity is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter(severity=severity)

if source is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter(source=source)

if start is not None and end is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter(date__range=(start, end))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(severity=severity) | Q(severity__isnull=True), date__range=(start, end))
```

**__isnull** is used to check for NULL data.

Also no need of using **&** for **MYSQL 'AND'** as **filter checks using 'AND' by default**.